# Chartjs, scatter with For-Loop

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, chart.js, xhtml

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />  
        <title>Charts</title>
        <script src="./OurScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <style>

        </style>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>

        
        
    </head> 
    <body>
      
    <canvas id="myChart1"></canvas>
        

    <script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[

         
    var x = new Chart(document.getElementById("myChart1"), {
    type: 'scatter',
    data: {
        datasets: [{
            label: "Test",
            data: [
{x:0,y:3},{x:1,y:4},{x:2,y:2},{x:3,y:5},{x:4,y:7},{x:5,y:5},{x:6,y:7},{x:7,y:8},{x:8,y:4},{x:9,y:4}
],
                        }]
                    },
                    options: {
                        responsive: true
                    }
                    });

        
       //]]> </script>
        
           
          

    </body>
</html>
```

Thats my Code which works fine. (I need to use XHTML)

My Problem is, I want to use a for Loop for the X and Y Values. But I dont know how to put the Array in data.

I tried something like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />  
        <title>Charts</title>
        <script src="./OurScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <style>

        </style>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>

        
        
    </head> 
    <body>
      
        
        

            <canvas id="myChart1"></canvas>
        

        <script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[

            var xwerte = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
            var ywerte = [3,4,2,5,7,5,7,8,4,4];
           var c = [];
           var Ergebnis1;
           for(var i=0;i<ywerte.length;i++)
            {
            var obj ="{" + "x:" + xwerte[i] + "," + "y:" + ywerte[i] + "}";
                c.push(obj);
                
            }
           
           
           
         // alert(c);
            var x = new Chart(document.getElementById("myChart1"), {
                    type: 'scatter',
                    data: {
                        datasets: [{
                            label: "Test",
                            data: [c],
                        }]
                    },
                    options: {
                        responsive: true
                    }
                    });

        
       //]]> </script>
        
           
          

    </body>
</html>
```

I tried with "alert" and I got the right result. But how should  I put "c" in data?

I think I dont see a little (hopefully) mistake.

I need to use XHTML and just JavaScript.
On Snippet there is a error, but as I said, I am using XHTML and there is no Error.

Comment: Also the way you're making the chart object is incorrect. Your array elements should be JavaScript objects, not strings that *look like* objects.

Comment: How should it look like? Im sorry but I really dont know. I am trying right now some but...

Comment: `var obj = { x: xwerte[i], y: ywerte[i] };`

Comment: That works, but how can I put it into data : [  ] . Just "c" doesnt work.

Comment: You need to use "c" and not "[c]". "c" already is an array. You don't need nested arrays.

Comment: @Alohci yea that's correct, I realized that later but never came back to delete the comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually I set up my objects and arrays how I need them at first and then fill them with data.

Set it up:

```
var chartData = {
  datasets: [{
    label: 'Test',
    data: []
  }]
}
```

Fill it with data:

```
for (var i = 0; i < yWerte.length; i++) {
  chartData.datasets[0].data.push(
    {
      x: xWerte[i], // You don't need "xWerte", you can simply use "i" when it's always the increment
      y: yWerte[i]
    }    
  )
}
```

You don't need your `c` to save your data, you can just use it like I did. But if you want `c` you can save the result of the for-loop in the empty array `c` and then use `chartData.datasets[0].data = c`.

**Working example with live-preview: https://jsbin.com/copiwefaza/edit?js,output**